# Cannot Ping endpoints across a VPLS connected VLAN

Tags: router, vlan, mpls, vpls

Created a new VPLS Service first manually and then when it did not work reattempted with our Alcatel SAM 5620 to get a VLAN to pass end to end.

Both configs look the same, neither the command line method nor the GUI method brought it up. Looking through the config, it is near identical to all prior VPLS in the 7450-ESS-6 and 7450-ESS-1. The configs were checked line by line by two different people and we have not found an error.

```
Physical  Setup =>  Equip <--Port--ESS6--Router Port--><--Router Port--ESS1(1st Hop)--Router Port-->Router Port--ESS1(2nd Hop)--Port-->Equip

Logical Setup VPLS Service over MPLS LSP => Equip <--SAP--ESS6--SDP--><--MPLS OSPF LSP--><--SDP--ESS1--SAP--> Equip
```

Service shows up in SAM from end to end with no errors.
Each End ESS can ping the System IP Address of the other ESS.
ESS6 holding the VLAN Routing information of 10.0.248.1/21
Devices currently in this range have 10.0.255.1-254
ESS6 can ping 10.0.248.1
ESS1 on other end can ping 10.0.248.1

All other services to site and ports are working.
Ran "show service id <#> fdb detail on both ends and the VPLS shows the MAC address of the equipment passing from either end.
It appears to be a Layer 3 issue.

Ran Traceroute from Equipment ends cannot ping the router 10.0.248.1

Traceroute to device shows 
0.0.0.0             * * *
0.0.0.0             * *
10.0.248.1/21   96ms  !H 
repeated

Traceroute from device
Shows no route to destination.

Routing Table on ESS6 shows 10.0.248.1/21 Local

I feel I am passing over something and am a bit perplexed. It seems like there is no ARP traffic being to other end or the OSPF MPLS link is updating dynamically for this VLAN.  My next thought is to put static ARP through sites, but I thought this should be unnecessary.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Any help, ideas, test commands I should try to see result would be helpful. Thanks ahead of time.